# jQuery Date picker range depend in Duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

My loan form:

[image: this is my loan application]
If the cashier:

- picks the Date Granted "2016/12/13", and
- puts Duration of loan "5" 5 means 5 months.
- the due date automatically be populated with "2017/5/13" ("2016/12/13" + 5 months)

How can I change my code so the cashier can pick a date in the month of "2017/5"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/8FHwL/2406/

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution with an event hander to set the second date
Html:

```
    <input type="text" id="start" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="stop" />
```

javascript/jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#start").datepicker({
                onSelect: function () {
                    var d = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
                    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 5);
                    $("#stop").datepicker("setDate", d);
                }
            });
            // set start to today
            $("#start").datepicker( "setDate", Date.now());

            // this initializes the second one to today + 5 months
            $("#stop").datepicker();
            var datePlus5 = ($("#start").datepicker("getDate"));
            datePlus5.setMonth(datePlus5.getMonth() + 5);
            $("#stop").datepicker("setDate", datePlus5);

        });
```